# How to add native library .so file in java netbeans

Tags: java

how to link native library .so file in netbeans

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lib in java.library.path

Comment: you can find the library path using this System.setProperty("java.library.path"); and can add file with this location

Comment: @BuntyMadan `System.getProperty()` not `System.setProperty()`

Comment: @LoganDam first confirm about         
System.getProperty("java.library.path");

Answer (score 2):

Add the directory where the `.so` is stored to the `java.library.path` or add the library to a directory already in the path or use the full path name of the library.  The last option may be the most robust if you have a way of determining what it is.

Answer (score 1):

Set library path `-Djava.library.path=library\path` where your ***.so file resides.

Comment: I had add the following in VM Option :-Djava.library.path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_13\bin\*.so"  as well as the lib in the mentioned directory but it still throws an exception

Answer (score 0):

UnsatisfiedLinkError is shown because no library with the specified name has been found in your java.library.path

Before loading your library:

```
System.setProperty("java.library.path", "path_to_your_library");
```

Comment: it still throws an exception